# How to duplicate Posterous' flash player

Tags: mp3, flash

When you email an MP3 to Posterous, it gets automatically converted into this nice player for display on your blog:

[image]

Assuming I have a place to host the MP3, what's the best way to duplicate this on my personal site? E.g., are there any slick free flash MP3 players? How hard would it be to build my own?

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/) good enough? It's open source and if you know flash you can make it look more fancy.